# Is SNA DLC traffic compatible?

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

My question involves the compatibility the with SNA DLC traffic. In the pass with ESX 3.5 an incident had been logged with this protocol.

Here are the links of this problem:
http://communities.vmware.com/message/823536#823536
http://communities.vmware.com/message/953976#953976

Is this incident resoled with ESX4 and VSphere 4 , will I have any problems if I migration my VMware 3.5 to 4?

Thank you

Comment: Good question (for old timers like me anyway :) ) but I don't know the answer sorry.

Answer (score 1):

According to the community post, it may be fixed as of 3.5u1:

http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1003696

"7. Fixes a network connectivity issue where packets with an 802.2LLC header (without SubNetwork Access Protocol (SNAP)) are dropped by the vmxnet driver in ESX Server 3.5. This issue has been observed with NetBEUI and SNA/DLC protocols."

I would imagine the fix carries on through all version after 3.5u1.